# Command that creates new command based on argument

Tags: macros, arguments, csname

I want to have a command called `\ensureinfocommand` that can be called like this:

```tex
\ensureinfocommand{studentid}
```

This call will check if the command `\studentid` already exists and if not, it should create the following:

```tex
\newcommand\studentid[1]{
    \newcommand\@studentid{#1}
}
```

I tried implementing `\ensureinfocommand` like the following:

```tex
\newcommand\ensureinfocommand[1]{
    \ifcsname#1\endcsname\else
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{
            \expandafter\newcommand\csname @#1\endcsname{##1}
        }
    \fi
}
```

This creates all the necessary commands, but the output of `\@studentid` is wrong.

```tex
\ensureinfocommand{studentid}
\studentid{1234567}

\begin{document}
\@studentid
\end{document}
```

This prints `studentid` and not `1234567` and I don't get why. Does anybody see what's wrong with my commands?

Comment: don't show only snippets, always make a small but complete example, that makes testing much easier.

Comment: Are you aware of `\providecommand`?  It's like `\newcommand`, but only executes if the command doesn't already exist.  So it would save you from the `\ifcsname` part.

Comment: @Teepeemm no, I was not ware of `\providecommand`. Thanks for pointing me to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `\makeatletter` in using `\@studentid`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ensureinfocommand[1]{%
    \ifcsname#1\endcsname\else
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname#1\endcsname[1]{%
            \expandafter\newcommand\csname @#1\endcsname{##1}%
        }%
    \fi
}

\ensureinfocommand{studentid}
\studentid{1234567}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter\@studentid\makeatother
\end{document}
```

I also took the liberty to add suitable `%`'s to avoid extraneous space tokens.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I had not thought of that at all!